# Sorting on Custom Attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have an attribute I created called "sales_rank" that I have set to use as a sortable attribute.  However, when I choose it from the product list, it is not sorting how I expect.  On further inspection, it appears that it's sorting as a *text field* and not as a *number*.  This means that it will go 101, 1014, 102, 1035, 104, 11, 1204, etc....

How do I fix this?  When creating the attribute, there's no way to tell it it's a number.  You can select "Integer" from the "Input Validation" box, so is that the answer?  I haven't tried it yet...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try that and come back if it continues not to work. Data fields can be saved in several tables, and it sounds like you are saving this field as a string (as evidenced by the alphabetical sort).

If you really want to know where it is saved, run this query against your database:

```
select backend_type from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'sales_rank';
```

You want that to say number/integer, etc.

Comment: Thanks @joseph-mastey, but unfortunately that didn't seem to work.  I tried your suggestion on the current attribute and it is, in fact, a **varchar**.  However, I tried creating a new attribute, this time selecting "Integer" for the "Input Validation" option, but it is once again a **varchar**.  I also tried getting all attributes who's **backend_type** is **int**.  The results are all _Dropdown_ & _Yes/No_ attribute types, but I can't use those in this case.  Is there a way to have a _Text Field_ style attribute(in terms of how you enter the value) that is actually an _Integer_ value?

Comment: BTW, I was able to fix the sorting issue by padding the strings with leading '0's so that they sort properly...but I don't like this solution, so if anyone knows the proper way, please let me know :)

Comment: Brian, what do you mean by padding the strings with leading '0's? I'm also having this problem!

Comment: Actually, I think I know what you mean: 

0010
0020
0030

etc up to 9999

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=7204

Basically, use the 'price' attribute type because the system sees it as an integer. Not pretty, but it works a treat!